# My UIButton does not disable on touch?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, storyboard

I created a `UIButton` in **storyboard**, declared it as an outlet in the .h and for some reason neither

```
    addflight.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

or

```
    addflight.enabled=NO;
```

disables it, I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please Check if you have connect the IBOutlet from .h file to nib.
Also see if there is no view above your button. See UserInteraction Enabled.
[See The Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).
[See this tut](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iOS_6%29).

Comment: I have a view above the button, is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, its not allowing the touch to pass to button. [Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You can call ` [self.view bringSubviewToFront: myButton];`